# Clojure: filter list of maps by 2nd list

Tags: list, dictionary, filter, clojure

Got a list of maps like

```
({:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"}
 {:a "d" :b "e" :c "f"}
 {:a "g" :b "h" :c "i"}
 {:a "j" :b "k" :c "l"})
```

and a 2nd list like `("c" "i")`.

I need to filter the list of maps by the 2nd lists entries for a result like as

`({:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"} {:a "g" :b "h" :c "i"})`

but dont get a clue how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
(def data
   (list
     {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"}
     {:a "d" :b "e" :c "f"}
     {:a "g" :b "h" :c "i"}
     {:a "j" :b "k" :c "l"}))
```

Then

```
=> (filter (comp (set (list "c" "i")) :c) data)
({:a "a", :b "b", :c "c"} {:a "g", :b "h", :c "i"})
```

- Your lists need `list` as the operator (or to be quoted).
- I assume you want to filter by the value for key `:c`, which need not be the second entry in the printed map.

You need to get to grips with two or three aspects of Clojure:

- How sequence functions like `filter` work.
- Using sets and keywords as functions.
- What `comp` does.